# combine specific objects in a list

Tags: r, list

"a" is a list.

```
> a<-list(1,2,3,c(4,5),6,7)
> a
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 4 5

[[5]]
[1] 6

[[6]]
[1] 7
```

"b" is a transform indicator.

```
b<-c(3,2,1)
```

I want group(or combine) objects in "a" according to the number in "b", that means the first 3 objects group together, then the next two, finally the last, the expected result is as follows:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 4 5 6

[[3]]
[1] 7
```

I can only use "cumsum" to sum the three groups, but don't know how to display each object as listed above. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is

```
lapply(split(a, cumsum(sequence(b)==1)), unlist)
#$`1`
#[1] 1 2 3

#$`2`
#[1] 4 5 6

#$`3`
#[1] 7
```

Comment: `Julius<-function() tapply(a, rep(seq_along(b), b), Reduce, f = `c`);
akrun<-function() lapply(split(a, cumsum(sequence(b)==1)), unlist);
identical(Julius(),akrun())
[1] FALSE`why are they not the same?

Comment: @lightsnail  It must be because of some attributes in the `Julius()` output.  Try `all.equal(akrun(), Julius(), check.attributes=FALSE)#
[1] TRUE`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I find `cumsum(sequence(b)==1))` and `rep(seq_along(b), b)`are the same, and non-logical sentence is a little faster than logical sentence, so based on @Julius 's and your code,  `lapply(split(a, rep(seq_along(b), b), unlist)` can achieve the fastest speed. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

```
tapply(a, rep(seq_along(b), b), Reduce, f = `c`)
$`1`
[1] 1 2 3

$`2`
[1] 4 5 6

$`3`
[1] 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Another attempt:

```
grps <- rep(rep(seq_along(b), b), lengths(a))
relist(unlist(a), split(grps,grps) )

#$`1`
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#$`2`
#[1] 4 5 6
#
#$`3`
#[1] 7
```